# How to make field required depending on relationship data?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-10, filamentphp

Package Versions:

- PHP 8.2.12
- Laravel 10.28.0
- Filamentphp v3

I would like to make the `copy_permis` field required or not depending on the specialty selected.

I have two models `Candidat(id,name,specialty_id)` and `Specialty(id,name,is_required )`. NB: is_required : is boolean

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('specialty_id')
->required()
->live()
->searchable()->preload()
->relationship('specialty','name'),

Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('copie_permis')
->directory('permis_files')
->openable()
->downloadable()
->image()
->imageEditor()
->required(fn (Get $get): bool => ($get('specialty_id.is_required') == true)),
```

I expect to check the value of is_required to decide if it's required or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
->required(fn (Get $get): bool => Specialite::select('cp_requise')->where('id', $get('specialite_id'))->pluck('cp_requise')->join('/'))
```